# If $E$ is a real vector space, then its dual space $E'$ is a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

If $E$ is a real vector space, then its dual space $E'$ is a Banach space?

I know the answer to a question above is yes in the case that $E$ is a normed vector space. Now if we remove the hypothesis of being normed, is that still true?

Comment: You can't define the operator norm on $E^*$ without a norm on $E$

Comment: But you need a norm for a space to be Banach. How do you turn the dual into a normed space if you don't have a norm on $E$?

Comment: In fact, if $E$ is only a vector space with no topological structure then you don't even have the right notion of dual space available. Note that for a normed space the topological dual $E^*$ consisting of **continuous** linear functionals is a Banach space but the space of all linear functionals is not naturally a Banach space. Without topological structure you can't even identify the right space of functionals to use.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but I have already seen an exercise that says that in any vector space, a norm can be defined. Maybe it has to do with it.

Comment: Yes, you can always define a norm, but norms in general are not equivalent, so a space might be Banach in one norm but not in another. If $E$ is a normed space then its dual $E'$ is Banach specifically in the operator norm (which is the interesting norm we can define on it), doesn't mean it is Banach in any norm.

Comment: Excellent observation, now I understand that it doesn't work